# Numpy method for "getting argmin per group"

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to find an efficient, numpy-looping (as opposed to python-looping) way of doing the getting the indices of the lowest-cost data point per group.  Something like what `np.minimum.at` does but with the "argminimum" instead of the minimum.  (and `np.argmin.at` does not exist).

The following demonstrates what I'm looking for:

```
    names, groups, costs = zip(*[
        ('a', 0, 2.0),  # no (d is lower cost)
        ('b', 1, 3.),  # yes (tied but first)
        ('c', 2, 3.),  # yes (only one)
        ('d', 0, 1.2),  # yes
        ('e', 3, 3.),  # no (k is lower)
        ('f', 4, 3.),  # no (j is lower)
        ('g', 5, 3.),  # yes
        ('h', 1, 3.),  # no (tied but not first)
        ('i', 0, 4.),  # no (d is lower)
        ('j', 4, 2.3),  # yes
        ('k', 3, 0.6),  # yes
        ('l', 5, 7.),  # no (g is lower)
    ])
    mask = get_minimal_unique_index_mask(arr=np.array(groups), values=np.array(costs))
    selected = ''.join(c for c, m in zip(names, mask) if m)
    expected = 'bcdgjk'
    assert selected == expected, f"Selected: '{selected}'.  Expected: '{expected}'"
```

I'm trying to find an efficient implementation of `get_minimal_unique_index_mask`.  I know I could easily do this with dicts and python loops:

```
def get_minimal_unique_index_mask(groups: Array['N', Any], values: Array['N', float]) -> Array['N', bool]:
    min_ixs_vals = {}
    for i, (group, val) in enumerate(zip(groups, values)):
        if group not in min_ixs_vals:
            min_ixs_vals[group] = i
        else:
            min_ixs_vals[group] = i if val < values[min_ixs_vals[group]] else min_ixs_vals[group]
    argmin_per_group_mask = np.zeros(len(groups), dtype=bool)
    argmin_per_group_mask[list(min_ixs_vals.values())] = True
    return argmin_per_group_mask
```

... The above works, but loops in python and thus will be slow.  I'm wondering if there's a clever numpy-way to do the same.

Comment: I'd probably use pandas' groupby functionality for this.

Comment: Thanks Quang, I tried that and seem to have a working function now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out how to do it with Pandas.  Not sure if the looping is in efficient C-code though:

```
def get_minimal_unique_index_mask(groups: Array['N', Any], values: Array['N', float]) -> MaskArray:
    ixs = pd.DataFrame({'groups': groups, 'values': values}).groupby('groups')['values'].idxmin().values.astype(int)
    argmin_per_group_mask = np.zeros(len(groups), dtype=bool)
    argmin_per_group_mask[ixs] = True
    return argmin_per_group_mask
```

Thanks to Marcos from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57180166/851699)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the pandas version was slow.  It's 60x faster to just loop in python, which is probably still slow compared to implementing in C++

```
def get_minimal_unique_index_mask(groups: Array['N', Any], values: Array['N', float]) -> MaskArray:
    group_to_min_ix_val = {}
    for i, (g, v) in enumerate(zip(groups, values)):
        g = str(g)
        if g not in group_to_min_ix_val:
            group_to_min_ix_val[g] = (i, v)
        else:
            _, vmin = group_to_min_ix_val[g]
            if v < vmin:
                group_to_min_ix_val[g] = (i, v)

    argmin_per_group_mask = np.zeros(groups.shape, dtype=bool)
    for i, _ in group_to_min_ix_val.values():
        argmin_per_group_mask[i] = True

    return argmin_per_group_mask
```